# Is there a way to group by the date portion of a datetime field in SOQL

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

This [soql](/questions/tagged/soql) returns results count base on day;

```
SELECT day_only(createdDate) createdonDate, 
    count(createdDate) numCreated 
FROM account 
GROUP BY day_only(createdDate) 
ORDER BY day_only(createdDate) desc
```

But i want the result count be based on month.

Is there a way to achieve this in soql?

Answer (score 2):

Use CALENDAR_MONTH function:

```
SELECT CALENDAR_MONTH (createdDate) createdonDate, 
       count(ID) numCreated 
FROM account 
GROUP BY CALENDAR_MONTH (createdDate) 
ORDER BY CALENDAR_MONTH (createdDate) desc
```